# How to free memory in MIPS allocated by sbrk call?

Tags: assembly, memory-management, mips, mars-simulator

In implementation of a linked-list using MIPS, I am ask to delete a note when user asks. It is easy to change the pointers so the node is no longer accessible from the list. But the node still exits on the heap, occupying memory space.
This works in Java because of its garbage collection feature. 
In languages like C we can call a function to deallocate the memory. 
However, in MIPS, I failed to find such a feature or function.

So my question is: is there a function in MIPS to free up memories allocated by the sbrk function?
If not, would assigning the word I want to free to zero actually frees the memory? (i.e. sbrk  can use this memory for new data)

Thank you!

Comment: Use `sbrk` with a negative increment.

Comment: Could you please give me an example? Thank you!

Comment: Surely you don't need an example of a negative number ... if you allocated 100 bytes using `sbrk(100)` you can free those using `sbrk(-100)`. Note that `sbrk` just moves the end of your heap, if you have holes in your data, you have to take care of that yourself.

Comment: Ohh...I see....I was think of deleting in the middle of the heap..Looks like it's not the right way to do. Your comments helped me a lot. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Jester can you post an answer ?

Comment: Actually in spim, it gives you an error if you use negative numbers with sbrk

Comment: And also in Mars it gives an error if you use negative numbers with sbrk.

Comment: @Jester That's not how sbrk works in MIPS.

Comment: Right, there was some confusion about `sbrk` library function in general and `sbrk` system call in MARS/SPIM (which is an unfortunate naming choice).

Comment: "surely you dont need an example of a negative number", yet doesn't provide valid answer Lol